# rpy2 on pycharm generates segmentation fault error

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, rpy2

I am using (osx) pycharm as ide and anaconda as python (2.7.10) distribution.
Recently I have installed rpy2 which works quite well on notebook e.g.

```
In [5]:import rpy2.robjects as robjects
In [7]:robjects.r.pi[0]
Out[7]:3.141592653589793
```

But on pycharm I get a segmentation fault error.

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
/Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/analytics3/bin/python.app: line 3: 695 Segmentation fault: 11 /Users/xxx/anaconda/envs/analytics3/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python "$@"
```

PYcharm support claims that this is a bug in the code.

any ideas what that might be?

many thanks

Comment: Most probably not pycharm's fault, yes. But with that little information it's probably impossible to find the one to blame.

Comment: thanks for the reply. that is all i unfortunately have. where would you start if you wanted to dig in?

Comment: reinstalling rpy2 from
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/r rpy2

solved the issue. thanks

Comment: You may want to add this as an answer to mark the problem as solved!

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling rpy2 from

```
conda install -c conda.anaconda.org/rpy2
```

solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you install rpy2 via conda, and also have a system installation of R on the same machine (e.g with RStudio), the system's R installation will be used. Since this R version doesn't match the one that rpy2 needs, segmentation faults occur.

1) remove any existing system installations of R ([see here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Uninstalling-under-OS-X)). Verify that you don't have any installations of R:

```
$>which R
R not found
```

2) define `R_HOME` env variable, either in your .rc file:

```
export R_HOME=/Users/<your user>/anaconda3/envs/<env name>/lib/R
```

or dynamically in the python project:

```
import os
os.environ['R_HOME'] = '/Users/<your user>/anaconda3/envs/<env name>/lib/R'
```